# Can I move CM or CD installations across partitions?

Tags: configuration, infrastructure

**Background**: I'm attempting to extend the boot volume (C:) on the following SDL Tridion setup:

- `C:\` has the OS, programs, and databases
- `D:\` has the CMS and Content Delivery (all-in-one demonstration/training setup)
- AWS EC2 instance (based on an AMI) with Windows Server 2008 RC2

I'm not able to add extend `C:\` by adding space when creating a new instance because the un-allocated space isn't contiguous. Per [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771473.aspx):

> "For logical drives, boot, or system volumes, you can extend the
>   volume only into contiguous space and only if the disk can be upgraded
>   to a dynamic disk."

I'm able to:

1. Copy `D:\` which includes `%TRIDON_HOME%` to a **new volume**
2. Delete the old `D:\`
3. Rename new volume to `D:\`
4. Extend `C:\` as needed

*After a everything is in the right place except Window access .*

**Questions**:

**Has anyone done the same and are there any "gotchas" to doing this?** The paths end up being the same and folder permissions seemed to transfer over okay, but I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Recommendations on a move with path changes (i.e. moving `%TRIDION_HOME%` from `C:\` to `D:\`, for example) also appreciated.

**Update**: Revisiting a mistake I made in delivery. The Windows CD folder permissions aren't the same (deployment fails when trying to commit with `Access is denied`).

It looks like you need to cut & paste when on the same volume, otherwise you have to reset Windows permissions at least for Windows 2008. See this [post](http://www.winplat.net/post/2011/04/08/How-file-and-folder-permissions-are-handled-while-moving-or-copying-files-on-Windows-2008-R2-and-Windows-7.aspx) that shows moves and copies are treated the same across volumes (target setting inherited regardless).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two approaches:

A - If the C and D drives are two separate EBS Volumes, you can do the following:

1. Shut down the instance
2. Take snapshot of existing volume
3. Create new volume based on snapshot. During this step you determine the new size.
4. Detach old volume
5. Attach new larger volume.
6. Extend the volume in Windows.

B - If they belong to a single EBS Volume, which is likely the case since you are receiving the error:

1. Create a new partition using the unallocated space and call it drive E for now
2. Move D’s content to it via robocopy with switches `/R:0` `/MIR` `/SEC`.
3. Delete the old D drive and extend C to use this new space.
4. When done, just change E’s drive letter back to D.

Comment: +1 and accepted, thanks Shelton! Approach *B* worked in my case--the robocopy switches helped get past the Windows permission problem. You were right, this setup had two *logical* drives on the same EBS volume. So though I could extend the volume on EC2 instance creation or by following your "A" steps, the new space wasn't "contiguous" to `C:\`.

Answer (score 8):

These days, a fresh install of the CM is pretty painless. Just uninstall and then re-install where you wanted it. Any CD installations you have can probably just be copy/pasted, with the proviso that you fix up any hard-coded file system locations in your configs and publication targets.

Answer (score 7):

One gotcha that made me pull hairs: look in the Windows Registry for the old path (`C:\`) and replace it with the new one.

I saw weird behaviour because of that on both CM and CD.

Obviously then, check all your config files (`%TRIDION_HOME%\conf`) and search and replace old/new paths. For example logback paths and explicit mentions of license files.

In the CME, check the paths for Publication Targets, in case you are using `local file system` transport.